# settings to allow htacess file to work?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have placed my htacess file in a directory where I want to use this
like this

`C:\wamp\www\test\index.php`

`C:\wamp\www\test\h1.php`

`C:\wamp\www\test\h2.php`
and

`C:\wamp\www\test\default.htacess`

I have a code in this file that if user enters url with 1 parameter it redirects it to h1.php and if 2 then h2.php but it gives error for example

*http://localhost:8080/test/first*

should redirtect to 
*http://localhost:8080/test/h1.php* 
but says

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /test/first was not found on this server.

my htaccess code is

```
 php_value allow_url_fopen On

 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ h1.php?parent=$1 [QSA,L]
 RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ h2.php?parent=$1&child=$2 [QSA,L]
 RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?parent=$1&child=$2&subchild=$3 [QSA,L]
```

1-Tell me I have placed file at proper place

2-this is httpd.conf file setting I did

```
 <Directory /var/www/>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Allow from all
   RewriteEngine on

 </Directory>
```

now I have not changed any php.ini file I am going right how to do that

Comment: Have you tried to rename `default.htacess` to just `.htaccess` (two _c_'s and without the _default_)? Don't forget to restart Apache after you've made changes to `httpd.conf`. You don't need to change your `php.ini` to get htaccess to work.

Comment: error `you must type a file name` for only `.htacess`

Comment: That's a Windows limitation when you change the name through Explorer. Change it through CMD instead. The filename must be: `.htaccess` only, or it won't be read or used by Apache.

Comment: is it also necessary if we change the code in htacess file we must again restart apache

Comment: No. That file will be read on each request, anyway

Comment: post this answer below and also tell me if how to use `if else` like if i pass a fixed parameter like `dome` it redirect to h1 or another domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the file name from `default.htaccess` to `.htaccess`

And try restarting server along with clearing the cache to get it working.

Comment: can you also tell me if i pass a fix parameter like `dome` it redirect it to `h1.php` how

Comment: Try adding this on the top of all rules `RewriteRule ^h1.php h1.php?parent=dome [QSA,L]`

Comment: no its not working suppose in case of `dome` it redirect to h3.php  but if any other single parameter comes it redirect to h1.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41634835/how-to-get-the-value-of-parameter-in-htacess-and-handle-redirection