# How to change change URL format to POST using htacess php?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have `htaccess` tha handle redirections know i want to hit api like i have a url like that

http://localhost:8080/test/network/country/category/subcategory/fixedvalue

I have fixed value like `detail, category ,codes` but only in case of `detail` i need `id` as parameter

**example**

http://localhost:8080/test/Airtel/UK/Prepaid/5G/Detail

below is redirect url that i want to generate from htacess file
if fixed value is `detail`

http://localhost:8080/h1.php?network=Airtel&country=UK&category=Prepaid&subcategory=5G&Detail=`remain portion of url except .html`

in other cases where detail is not in fixed i don't need `id` that have parameter the remaining portion of url after 5th parameter so url will be

http://localhost:8080/h1.php?network=Airtel&country=UK&category=Prepaid&subcategory=5G

here is a code that redirect to `5.php` file so that but i want not redirection i want a specific url having parameter

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ 5.php?1=$1&2=$2&3=$3&4=$4&5=$5  [QSA,L]
```

in simple from

`www.cloth.com/nike` to `www.cloth.com?name=nike`

Comment: CAN ANY BODY HELP ME WITH THAT

Comment: HELLO PLEASE DO SOME THING